# Sample Apps for lower Api levels for android

Tags: android

Browsing [google's sample webpage for android](http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html) i found that several apps required high minSdkVersion

(for example the NFC example requires Api level 19)

where can i find the Samples for lower Api levels that were once on that same page?

Comment: you can use support libraries. But about nfc if your device not support nfc you cannot test nfc app on that device and you can access libraries from : http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: my device runs JB 4.3 and supports NFC, but the sample app calls for api level 19 functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Android SDK Manager to download the various SDKs to your machine, each SDK comes with its own version appropriate set of sample code that you can download at the same time.